# Little round knobs under the ark of the covenant

Tags: part-identification

I'd like to build [the ark of the covenant](https://ideas.lego.com/projects/4b1ad5ea-f390-4710-bcdb-dd8c6c042113/comments_tab#content_nav_tabs) from LEGO IDEAS as part of my 'raiders of the Lost Ark' scene. Is there a way to get a parts list for a LEGO IDEAS submission? If not, can someone identify those little round knobs at the base of it. Can someone help me understand how he's attaching the bars to the ark?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since I'm not the author I won't be able to provide instructions, however it is quite easy for me to identify the pieces you are asking about.

"Little round knobs" are [Brick, Round 2 x 2 Sphere with Stud / Robot Body](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=20953#T=C) (20953)

[image]

Bars are attached with the help of [Plate, Modified 1 x 1 with Light Attachment - Thick Ring](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4081b#T=C) (4081b)

[image]

That's how it would look in the assembly:

[image]